# PHP fputs and fsockopen

Tags: php

I'm a .net developer and this piece of PHP is really confusing me....

```
$ptr=@fsockopen(T_HOST,T_PORT,$errno,$errstr,T_TIMEOUT); 
if($ptr)
        {
//--- If having connected, request and collect the result
         if(fputs($ptr,"W$query\nQUIT\n")!=FALSE)
           while(!feof($ptr)) 
             {
              if(($line=fgets($ptr,128))=="end\r\n") break; 
              $ret .= $line;
             } 
         fclose($ptr);
```

If T_HOST is 123.100.98.209, T_PORT is 443 and $query is "QUOTES-EURUSD", what kind of request does this piece of code produce?

While this PHP code does return something, when I try "http://123.100.98.209:443/QUOTES-EURUSD" from the browser and postman, it just fails.

What's

> "\nQUIT\n"

doing in the query string?

And what does the "W" mean in front of the $query?

Sorry if these questions are too basic, I know nothing about PHP.

Comment: The use of the YOLO operator (`@`) is concerning here, that suppresses errors. Whomever wrote this really doesn't care about error checking.

Comment: I'd speculate that this is not for HTTP type services. this is for something else entirely, some simple line-based text protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opens a socket to 123.100.98.209

if that works tries to write to and get a response.

"QUOTES-EURUSD" - looking for the EUR to USD exchange rate

"\nQUIT\n" =\n is a line break "QUIT" is the string

"And what does the "W" mean in front of the $query?"

in this case a literal letter "W" i would suspect a typo here

Comment: The W could be part of the protocol.

Comment: It looks like a raw TCP request, not using a well-defined protocol. Thanks for the explanation.